# Any alternative to stackoverflow with chat function?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Does anyone know a website where noobs can actually engage and chat with programmer gurus? Stackoverflow is not quite the site for detailed discussions.

Comment: If you want more detail, ask in a comment.

Comment: Nor is it meant to be. Your regularly scheduled IRC channels are the place for that.

Comment: Dunno why you're getting so many downvotes. The FAQ say explicitly that SO is not a place for extended discussion.  Asking for a place that is seems valid to me.

Comment: Seems like a perfectly legit question to me. +1

Comment: I agree with Gordon - why downvote this one? I found the question useful myself.... certainly no reason to downvote it.

Comment: +1 from me as well. Once a question has a few answers and passes the first page most of the community seems to ignore it so this is a perfectly valid question IMO.

Comment: I have been submitting multiple posts (each with different questions) on the same subject and to date, I have not found the answer I am looking for. I have also figured out and read that SO is not intended for extended discussions...hence the question.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376707/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68591/282094

Answer (score 6):

Hop on irc channels. freenode is a good one. If it *must* be a website, you could use some webirc client perhaps to connect. But it would be easier and simpler to just use a normal client.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, how do I do so? What irc programs are available?

Thank you.

Comment: @2much2type, http://www.mirc.com/ for windows.  http://colloquy.info/ for mac.

Comment: Mirc is a good one if you use windows. Xchat is another good one if you're on a linux distro. I'm not sure for Mac OSX options, but they're out there.

Comment: http://www.mibbit.com/ is also good if you don't want to install a client (web based), or so I hear anyhow.

Comment: Some multi-protocol chat programs (e.g. Trillian, Pidgin) support IRC.

Comment: Thank you guys. I really appreciate your suggestions. :)

Comment: I like to use XChat on windows too (makes me feel more at home).

Answer (score 3):

I use #StackOverflow on slashnet. We discuss SO all the time.

I use [irssi](http://www.irssi.org/) as my client.

Answer (score 2):

[Usenet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet) is also great for this.  If you like, you can browse groups that interest you through [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/) before posing.

EDIT: also, see the answers to, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172818/other-sites-like-stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

I am of the opinion that it **is** the site for exactly that.  Just because the question has been answered, you can still discuss it.

Comment: SO is not meant for discussions by design.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a local user group and attend their meetings.