# General programming language questions in chat.stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, chat, site-recommendation

I would like to know a little bit more about the common use cases of certain programming languages and the optimal "combo" of programming languages (2 or 3).

I wish to learn which ones would be most useful in regards to longevity, so that I can stick with them (for a while at least).

This question was determined to be a duplicate, but by then I discovered that every SE site has a chat (https://chat.stackoverflow.com for stackoverflow, for example). I'd like to reopen this.

I read [this privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat) which includes :

> **When should I visit chat?**
>
> - for real time collaboration
> - to meet the fellow members of your community in a more social environment
> - for less structured, casual (but still roughly on-topic) conversation

Is it acceptable to ask my question in chat?

Comment: I don't think any of the sites accepts such questions.

Comment: Could you provide us with your specific example question?

Comment: @Glorfindel I edited my question after discovering the SE sites had chat rooms, thanks

Comment: Eh, sure i guess? chat rooms each have their own set of rules, some are open to general discussion, some prefer you stick to a specific topic, others may outlaw certain topics.

Comment: StijnB, you might want to read the results of the Developer Survey: https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/08/02/2021-stack-overflow-developer-survey-results/?_ga=2.147181751.1274924222.1646175205-1218227712.1646175205 and https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2021?_ga=2.147181751.1274924222.1646175205-1218227712.1646175205#technology-most-popular-technologies - and research some of the top languages to prepare your questions for the chat room you choose. Different rooms for different languages, and types of questions.

Comment: Sure, just make sure the room's rules actually allow such inquiries to be made in the first place. In general, rooms dedicated to a specific language are happy to share info on the language the room is dedicated to and often other langs (after all, many of us know pr are at least familiar with more than just one language).

Comment: Close voters: this is not a duplicate of the myriad of other questions asking "Where to ask programming questions" because it's clearly **focused on chat**. Chat is *not* a site. It is something different.

Comment: This appears to be on-topic here: [Always on Topic](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/10/loungec) C++ Lounge.